# Borderlands 3 100% achievements requires DLCs?

Tags: steam, achievements, borderlands-3

Borderlands 3 just launched on Steam this week. I can buy normal edition, deluxe or super deluxe.

My question is : are DLC required to 100% complete the game. I'm talking about Steam achievements.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears that you do indeed need DLCs to complete all the achievements for Borderlands 3.

Taking a look at the steam achievements [here](https://steamcommunity.com/stats/397540/achievements) we can see a total of 52 achievements being listed. When comparing to the base game we can see that this is 7 achievements above the base game amount. Having a deeper look it appears 7 the extra achievements come from Add-on: [Moxxi's Heist of the Handsome Jackpot](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1232256/Borderlands_3_Moxxis_Heist_of_the_Handsome_Jackpot/).

The achievements added from the DLC:

- A Proper Hand-Off
- Firebug
- Killer Look
- Scovillain
- Shoe Money Tonight
- Don't Be a Stranger
- Who Collects The Collector?

I would, however, note you can "complete" the game without the DLC, these are just extra side stuff that doesn't impact the main story.

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer! I like 100% games, so I think I have to take all Super Deluxe!